# Any Distros Built for Layer 3 Switching / Routing?

Tags: networking, routing, distribution-choice, router

I want to be able to have a decent router that can be highly configured and handle a fair amount of traffic while being secure. Before I spend money on some dedicated routing hardware/software, is it possible Linux can be used for this? Are their any distros that specialize in this?

Comment: If you buy dedicated hardware for this, chances are that it's running Linux under the hood. You'll need to spend the money on hardware anyway though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several that "specialize" in this listed at Wikipedia; YMMV. Too many to provide a full list, but...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_and_firewall_distributions

Openwall, Smoothwall, and ZeroShell look interesting. Many choices to pick from. If you aren't dead set on "Linux" I would consider pfSense (FreeBSD derivative).

Comment: Yeah, everyone seems to like pfSense. Guess I should try it. Thanks.